# Array in the IN operator

Tags: sql, plpgsql

Does someone know how can I use an array in the IN operator in plpgsql?

```
SELECT INTO unsolvedNodes array_agg(idDestination)
FROM road 
WHERE idOrigin IN ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below solved my problem.

```
SELECT INTO unsolvedNodes array_agg(idDestination)
FROM road
WHERE idOrigin = ANY(solvedNodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM entry_coll_tag
WHERE  entry_id = obj_id
AND tag_id = ANY(coll_ids);
```

It's just like that.